# aerospike udf error attempt to call method 'map' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, aerospike

my lua code is get from the example of offical website:

```
local function one(rec)
    info("lalalalal  %s",rec['id'])
    return 1
end
local function add(a, b)
    return a + b
end
function mycount(stream)
    return stream : map(one) : reduce(add);
end
```

when i use aql command:

error in logs such as blow:

> May 20 2015 07:12:07 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_rw.c:send_result:515)
>   FAILURE when calling stream_udf mycount
>   /opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/stream_udf.lua:10: attempt to call method
>   'map' (a nil value) May 20 2015 07:12:07 GMT: DEBUG (udf):
>   (udf_rw.c:send_udf_failure:403) Non-special LDT or General UDF
>   Error(/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/stream_udf.lua:10: attempt to call
>   method 'map' (a nil value))

how to solve it ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a Lua problem where it won't automatically convert nil to string, and the functions like print and info() expect that type. Change your line to

```
info("lalalalal  %s", tostring(rec['id']))
```